# Determining JPEG color encoding

Tags: python, pdf, jpeg

I'm currently working with PDF image extraction on **python3**.

I have finished the core logic and it works pretty fine.

The problem is, sometimes YCCK coded JPG file comes out from PDF, and it looks horrible with common image viewers.

I can covert YCCK image into CMYK but I can't figure out know how to determine if the image is YCCK, CMYK or YUV.

If i convert every image from YCCK to CMYK, it will break CMYK and YUV images.

I have searched few hours and only found [this](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2011/10/ycck-color-conversion-in-pdf-files/).

The article helped a lot but I can't use java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine the colorspace used, you have to parse the APPn blocks in the stream to determine the file format: JFIF, SPIFF, EXIF, ADOBE, etc. If you're getting it out of a PDF, the files are likely in ADOBE format. You'd need to check their documentation on how they use the APPn blocks.

Here is a page that has a summary:

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/JPEG.html#Adobe